# Does cudaFreeHost care what device is active when cudaMallocHost is used to allocate memory?

Tags: cuda

I am using Cuda SDK 4.0 and am encountering an issue which has taken me 2 days to whittle down into the following code.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
void main (int argc, char ** argv) {

    int* test;
    cudaError_t err;

    err = cudaSetDevice(   1   ); err = cudaMallocHost(&test, 1024*sizeof(int));    
    err = cudaSetDevice(   0   ); err = cudaFreeHost(test);    
}
```

This throws the following error when calling cudaFreeHost:

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007fefd96aa7d in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x0022f958..
```

The err value is `cudaErrorInvalidValue`

The same error occurs for this variation:

```
err = cudaSetDevice(   0   ); err = cudaMallocHost(&test, 1024*sizeof(int));    
err = cudaSetDevice(   1   ); err = cudaFreeHost(test);
```

The following variations dont throw the error:

```
err = cudaSetDevice(   0   ); err = cudaMallocHost(&test, 1024*sizeof(int));    
err = cudaSetDevice(   0   ); err = cudaFreeHost(test);
```

and

```
err = cudaSetDevice(   1   ); err = cudaMallocHost(&test, 1024*sizeof(int));    
err = cudaSetDevice(   1   ); err = cudaFreeHost(test);
```

I was under the impression you only needed to call cudaSetDevice if you want to allocate memory on a specific GPU. In the above example I am only allocating pinned memory on the CPU.

Is this a bug or did I miss something in the manual?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem. cudaHostAlloc and cudaMallocHost ***ARE NOT THE SAME***.

For anyone who encounters this problem the solution is to use

```
cudaHostAlloc(&test, 1024*sizeof(int),cudaHostAllocPortable);
```

instead of

```
cudaMallocHost(&test, 1024*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Unless UVA is in effect on the system [UVA transparently kicks in on CUDA 4.0, on 64-bit Linux.  It also is available in a limited way on Windows, if you are using TCC drivers], cudaMallocHost() only maps the host memory for the current device, and only that device can free the memory.  Making the host memory allocation "portable" maps the memory for all devices, and any device can free it.  This is why your solution worked.